# Delete Unique permissions for One-Drive Item through Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is there a way perform Delete Unique Permissions from [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0) API. As we can do this from the UI.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can delete only not inerited permissions.

```
var permissions = await _client
                .Drives[{ driveId }]
                .Items[{ itemId  }]
                .Permissions
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            foreach (var p in permissions)
            {
                if (p.InheritedFrom == null)
                {
                    await _client
                        .Drives[{ driveId }]
                        .Items[{ itemId  }]
                        .Permissions[p.Id]
                        .Request()
                        .DeleteAsync();
                }
            }
```